# AppleScript Library on an iCloud Drive Folder

Tags: macos, applescript, shared-libraries

is it possible to have a script (AppleScript & JavaScript) Library stored on a shared iCloud Drive folder? I'm relatively novice to coding (maybe a little over a year) and I can't make sense of this snippet:

> Any folders specified in the environment variable OSA_LIBRARY_PATH. This allows using a library without installing it in one of the usual locations. The value of this variable is a colon-separated list of paths, such as /opt/local/Script Libraries:/usr/local/Script Libraries. Unlike the other library locations, paths specified in OSA_LIBRARY_PATH are used exactly as-is, without appending “Script Libraries”. Supported in OS X v10.11 and later.

or...

> The network Library folder, /Network/Library. Libraries located here are available to multiple computers on a network.

from this article [Script Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_script_objects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH207-SW13)

I have it working perfectly from my /Users/username/Library/Script Libraries

but ive rallied in my neighbor to the project. He has access to my wifi, so a network drive would be okay. However, storing it in a shared folder in iCloud would be ideal.

There's also this link [OSA_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35389058/why-wont-osa-library-path-not-work-as-documented-for-jxa) but im having trouble translating it to iCloud. Hopefully someone can spell it all out for me...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Script Libraries are document files. iCloud service supports working with Documents folder.

So, first, **add (activate) at least one iCloud account** in the Internet Accounts pane of System Preferences.

Then double-click on icon of this account. Will appear litte button (**"Options..."**).
Set the **checkbox** for "Desktop & Documents folders".

Now close System Preferences, go --> HOME --> LIBRARY --> MOBILE DOCUMENTS. Create at this location new folder named "Script Libraries" and move your script libraries to it.

Now, you have custom "Script Libraries" folder on the iCloud storage.
OSA_LIBRARY_PATH for your "Script Libraries" you can get programatically:

```
POSIX path of (path to library folder from user domain) & "Mobile Documents/Script Libraries/"
```